# Default browser button background color

Tags: css, browser, input, colors, background-color

So check out these buttons:

[image]

they are unstyled, and look pretty good (the 2nd one is mouse over).

Can I somehow maintain their looks, but change the background color?

If I do it trough CSS's `background-color` property I get this:

[image]

Which doesn't really look like the others (it's not rounded, color is plain, doesn't have inner glow)...

Comment: The first two buttons cannot be un-styled or nothing would happen on mouse-over.  Are you sure those aren't images instead?

Comment: I mean I didn't style them... The browser just displays them like this if I don't style `<input>` ...

Comment: Which browser styles buttons like that?

Comment: Umm... no.  Unless they're images or have CSS applied, they will look different in every browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each browser has it's own styling. But using css you can achieve it. Check the following:

```
input {-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.16, rgb(207,207,207)),
    color-stop(0.79, rgb(252,252,252))
);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(207,207,207) 16%,
    rgb(252,252,252) 79%
);
padding:3px;
border:1px solid #000;}
```

### UPDATE

An updated version of the css button with `:hover` and gradient from the great site that @xec posted in the comment.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ekf5b/1

Helpful gradient generator: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

**Some additional information:** The first step is to add rounded corners. To set rounded corners in ie you can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/). Then add gradient using any tool that referred. Lastly I added `padding` for obvious reason, and `border` to override browser's default.

Comment: this gradient generator is pretty good too, adds support for most browsers (including old ie) and includes a few presets: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: The link redirects to some casino site.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons by default have some `padding`, and `border` settings applied to them. You will need to edit these settings as well to keep the button looking the same. It may also look different from browser to browser.

Look in the web debugger in Firefox (by getting firebug) or Google Chrome, right click and inspect element. This will show you the default css that is added to the buttons so that you can see how to edit them